# What are the different types of neural network or its hierarchical classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

As a beginner in ML and AI, I have come across ANN, RNN and LSTMs, however I would like to know what is the classification among neural networks ranging from the simplest single perceptron feedforward network to the most complicated one.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you'll be interested in looking at [the neural network zoo](http://www.asimovinstitute.org/neural-network-zoo/). It's not a hierarchical classification of all the different neural network types, but it does graphically show a lot of types and also provides short descriptions of them (and also some other models that are not typically considered to be neural networks). I haven't read through it all in detail, so I can't personally vouch for the page's correctness, but it looks good.

Comment: That's an awesome link.